Create a SwiftUI view that takes 3 other views as parameters two which are optional and one is required
Panel is a view that can take two optional views and one required view. You can have either header or footer or neither. Content is always required.
import SwiftUI

struct Panel<Content: View, Header: View, Footer: View>: View {
  let content: Content
  let header: Header?
  let footer: Footer?
  
  init(header: (() -> Header)? = nil, footer: (() -> Footer)? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
    self.header = header?()
    self.footer = footer?()
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      header
      
      content
      
      footer
    }
  }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      /// All views
      Panel(header: {
        Button("Header") {
          print("Got it!")
        }
        HStack {
          Text("Goodbye!!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }, footer: {
        Button("Footer") {
          print("Got it!")
        }
        HStack {
          Text("Goodbye!!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }) {
        VStack {
          Text("Hello!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }

      /// No header
      Panel(footer: {
        Button("Footer") {
          print("Got it!")
        }
        HStack {
          Text("Goodbye!!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }) {
        VStack {
          Text("Hello!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }

      /// No footer
      Panel(header: {
        Button("Header") {
          print("Got it!")
        }
        HStack {
          Text("Goodbye!!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }) {
        VStack {
          Text("Hello!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }
      
      /// No header nor footer
      Panel() {
        VStack {
          Text("Hello!")
          Text("World!")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The code above doesn't even compile (Using Xcode 15.4) so something is wrong in my declaration but I can't figure it out. I've seen some examples with one optional View but my application requires two. How can I setup Panel for this to work?

The code doesn't compile because you are treating the closures that Panel takes as if they are @ViewBuilder closures. In reality, only the content closure is a @ViewBuilder.
It is more idiomatic in SwiftUI to have multiple init overloads that take in different views, and use a where clause to specify what type the omitted views are. This way, every closure can be a @ViewBuilder. This is basically how the initialisers of the built-in Section are declared.
struct Panel<Content: View, Header: View, Footer: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    let header: Header
    let footer: Footer
    
    // note that I have changed the order of the parameters here!
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, @ViewBuilder header: () -> Header, @ViewBuilder footer: () -> Footer) {
        self.content = content()
        self.header = header()
        self.footer = footer()
    }
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, @ViewBuilder header: () -> Header) where Footer == EmptyView {
        self.init(content: content, header: header, footer: {})
    }
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content, @ViewBuilder footer: () -> Footer) where Header == EmptyView {
        self.init(content: content, header: {}, footer: footer)
    }
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) where Header == EmptyView, Footer == EmptyView {
        self.init(content: content, header: {}, footer: {})
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            header
            content
            footer
        }
    }
}

Example usage:
Panel {
    Text("Content 1")
    Text("Content 2")
} header: {
    Text("Header 1")
    Text("Header 2")
}


It is also possible to keep your current implementation of Panel unchanged (though I would not recommend this). You just need to wrap the multiple views you want to write in a Group { ... }, which is effectively a @ViewBuilder you get "for free".
Panel(header: {
    Group {
        Button("Header") {
            print("Got it!")
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Goodbye!!")
            Text("World!")
        }
    }
}, footer: {
    Group {
        Button("Footer") {
            print("Got it!")
        }
        HStack {
            Text("Goodbye!!")
            Text("World!")
        }
    }
}) {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello!")
        Text("World!")
    }
}

Now the code compiles even without the closures being @ViewBuilder, because the closures are simply returning a Group.

Very elegant solution! Not attached to my original implementation; so not sticking with it. Thank you!

One question: why did you prefer to move content as the first parameter? Just curious.

@Phantom59 Just to be consistent with other SwiftUI views, like Section.

Got it! Thanks, again!
